# Getting null values when deserializing a list using RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am new to C# and to RestSharp.

I am writing a small program to retrieve a list of records via REST.  I have been able to retrieve one record.  Now I need to get a list of records, and here I have a problem.

The response I get using SoapUI looks like this:

```
{
   "@count": 2,
   "@start": 1,
   "@totalcount": 2,
   "Messages": [],
   "ResourceName": "email",
   "ReturnCode": 0,
   "content":    [
      {"email": {"evsysseq": "0000000000000262"}},
      {"email": {"evsysseq": "0000000000000263"}}
   ]
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
class EmailID
{
    public string Evsysseq { get; set; }
}

var client = new RestClient("xxxxx");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("xxx", "xxx");
string queryParm = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("evsysseq>\"0000000000000261\"");

var request = new RestRequest("xxxx?query="+ queryParm, Method.GET);
request.RootElement = "content";
var queryResult = client.Execute<List<EmailID>>(request).Data;
```

Running it does not result in errors, and I can see on the `queryResult` object that it does contain two records.  But, `Evsysseq` is null on both, and that is my problem.  I am not sure what to tweak to get it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting null values because the JSON you are deserializing does not match the class structure you are deserializing into.  You are telling RestSharp to deserialize the `content` array into a `List<EmailID>`, but the JSON really represents a list of objects that *contain* `EmailID` objects.  And so you need another class:

```
class EmailObj
{
    public EmailID Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize like this and you should get the data:

```
var queryResult = client.Execute<List<EmailObj>>(request).Data;
```

If you want to, you can then use LINQ to get the `List<EmailID>` that you originally wanted like this:

```
var emailIds = queryResult.Select(eo => eo.Email).ToList();
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you Brian. Worked perfectly. Much appreciated.